# How to comapre two rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Consider the below rows in a table

```
ID  | Fname  | Lname   | Age | Weight 
-----------------------------------
23  | Kareem | Benzema | 30  | 75
24  | Karim  | Benzema | 32  | 75
```

I want to compare two rows and get difference between them.
My required result would be:

```
ColumnName | OldValue | NewValue
---------------------------------
ID         | 23       | 24
---------------------------------
Fname      | Kareem   | Karim
---------------------------------
Age        | 30       | 32
```

Comment: And what is the output when there are three rows? ten rows? This smells like a big [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: comparison is always between two rows.

Comment: What is a record? A row, a column, a value in a specific column in a specific row? SQL doesn't have "records" and its use to define something I'm SQL can be ambiguous.

Comment: @Larnu record is row of table.

Comment: _comparison is always between two rows_ Does that mean your table consists of only 2 rows? Or does that mean that you only compare 2 rows from the many (even if just 3) that exist in your table? And if so - which 2 rows do you compare? You supply an example that is very obvious to a person. Code does not "see" or "understand" obvious.

Comment: I compare rows before and after update.  to save log of changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...adjust..

```
declare @t table(ID int, Fname varchar(50), Lname varchar(50), Age tinyint, Weight smallint);

insert into @t(ID, Fname, Lname, Age, Weight)
values
(23, 'Kareem', 'Benzema', 30, null),
(24, 'Karim', 'Benzema', 32, 75);


select r1.[key], r1.value as oldvalue, r2.value as newvalue
from
(
    select 
        max(case when dt.rownum=1 then dt.thejson end) as row1,
        max(case when dt.rownum=2 then dt.thejson end) as row2
    from
    (   
        select 
            row_number() over(order by /*ID ?*/ @@spid) as rownum,
            (select t.* for json path, include_null_values, without_array_wrapper) thejson
        from @t as t
        where ID in (23, 24)--input
    ) as dt
) as src
cross apply openjson(src.row1) as r1
cross apply openjson(src.row2) as r2
where r1.[key] = r2.[key]
and (r1.value <> r2.value or r1.type <> r2.type) --type for null?
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm . . . let me assume that your values are all strings, since they are going to be stored in a column.  Then unpivot using `apply` and use `lag()`:

```
select v.columnName,
       lag(v.value) over (partition by v.columnName order by t.id) as oldValue,
       v.value as newValue
from t cross apply
     (values ('id', t.id),
              ('fname', t.vname),
              ('lname', t.lname),
              ('age', t.age),
              ('weight', t.weight)
     ) v(ColumnName, Value);
```

Finally, you want only changes, so use a subquery:

```
select v.*
from (select v.columnName,
             lag(v.value) over (partition by v.columnName order by t.id) as oldValue,
             v.value as newValue
      from t cross apply
           (values ('id', t.id),
                   ('fname', t.vname),
                   ('lname', t.lname),
                   ('age', t.age),
                   ('weight', t.weight)
           ) v(ColumnName, Value);
      ) v
where oldvalue <> newvalue;
```

Comment: I should mention column names. so for every table I should use a different query. can you suggest a more general solution which can be flexible and independent from column names?

Comment: @Behnam . . . (1) That would be a different question from the one you asked.  (2) You would need to write dynamic SQL to do what you want.